# Add class to next div after another div

Tags: jquery

Using jquery, how can I find all divs with the class `section-arrow`, then add the class `padded` to the next div with the class `main-section`?

So in the example, it's found the first div via `section-arrow`, then added the class `padded` to the next `main-section` div. Same applies to the 4th div.

```
<div class="main-section section-arrow"><div></div></div>
<div class="main-section padded"><div></div></div>
<div class="main-section"><div></div></div>
<div class="main-section section-arrow"><div></div></div>
<div class="main-section padded"><div></div></div>
```

---

```
<main id="content" class="site-content" role="main">

    <div class="main-section">
        <section class="row">           
            <div class="columns large-4">
                <div class="brandHeaderContent">

                </div>
            </div>       
        </section>
    </div>

    <div class="main-section section-arrow">
        <section class="row">           
            <div class="columns large-12">
                <div class="brandHeaderContent">

                </div>
            </div>       
        </section>
    </div>

    <style>
    .bannerStripHeader-<?php echo $backgroundColours; ?>:after {
    border-color: <?php echo $backgroundColour; ?> transparent transparent transparent;
    }
    .bannerStripHeader {
    padding-bottom:0px!important;
    }   
    </style>

    <div class="main-section serviceContentRow">
        <section class="row">
            <div class="columns">
                <div class="row">               
                    <div class="columns medium-6 brandHeaderContent">
                        (content)
                    </div>
                </div>          
            </div>
        </section>
    </div>

    <div class="main-section serviceContentRow">
        <section class="row">
            <div class="columns">       
                <div class="row">               
                    <div class="columns  brandHeaderContent">       

                    </div>
                </div>          
            </div>
        </section>
    </div>

    <div class="main-section section-arrow">
        <section class="row">           
            <div class="columns large-12">
                <div class="brandHeaderContent">

                </div>
            </div>   
        </section>
    </div>

    <style>
    .bannerStripHeader-<?php echo $backgroundColours; ?>:after {
    border-color: <?php echo $backgroundColour; ?> transparent transparent transparent;
    }
    .bannerStripHeader {
    padding-bottom:0px!important;
    }   
    </style>

    <div class="main-section serviceContentRow">
        <section class="row">
            <div class="columns">           
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="columns medium-6 brandHeaderContent">
                        (content)   
                    </div>
                </div>          
            </div>
        </section>
    </div>

</main>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do this you can simply select the `.section-arrow` elements and use the `next()` method. Try this:

```js
$('.section-arrow').next('.main-section').addClass('padded');
```

```css
.padded {
  border: 1px solid #C00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<main id="content" class="site-content" role="main">

  <div class="main-section">
    <section class="row">
      <div class="columns large-4">
        <div class="brandHeaderContent">
          brandHeaderContent 01
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  </div>

  <div class="main-section section-arrow">
    <section class="row">
      <div class="columns large-12">
        <div class="brandHeaderContent">
          brandHeaderContent 02
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  </div>

  <div class="main-section serviceContentRow">
    <section class="row">
      <div class="columns">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="columns medium-6 brandHeaderContent">
            (content)
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  </div>

  <div class="main-section serviceContentRow">
    <section class="row">
      <div class="columns">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="columns  brandHeaderContent">
            brandHeaderContent 03
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  </div>

  <div class="main-section section-arrow">
    <section class="row">
      <div class="columns large-12">
        <div class="brandHeaderContent">
          brandHeaderContent 04
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  </div>

  <div class="main-section serviceContentRow">
    <section class="row">
      <div class="columns">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="columns medium-6 brandHeaderContent" style="color:#000 !important;">
            (content)
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  </div>

</main>
```

Comment: I've tried a few attempts at this. I hadn't put the fact that each div has content within them so think it's throwing it. The only way I could select the second div was using this `$(".section-arrow").nextAll(".main-section").first().addClass("padded");` but for obvious reasons that didn't select the bottom div.

Comment: The content shouldn't affect it (in theory) as the `next*()` methods are based on the sibling elements. Could you edit the question to include a more accurate sample of your HTML and I'l take another look

Comment: Great thanks. Updated with new source, so the block of code immediately after the block with section-arrow should have padded added to it.

Comment: I updated the answer with the HTML in your question and it still seems ok.

Comment: Thanks for checking... really odd, it looks like it should work but just doesn't add the div. There isn't any errors either. If I change `.next` to `.nextAll` then it adds it to all the top level divs after the arrow... so there isn't a problem with it firing. Just don't understand why it doesn't work.

Comment: Is it possible you have a `.section-arrow` element somewhere on a parent element that's affecting your result?

Comment: I've found the problem, there was some style tags output between the divs (I've updated the question), when I take those out it works. How can I skip over those and only select the divs? (It's not my code so want to leave it as it was built)

Comment: I'd suggest a better solution would be to remove those `<style>` tags completely, if possible. They all seem to have the same broken logic anyway, so is there no way to remove them or change their functionality to use a common class in an external stylesheet?

Comment: Unfortunately no, I added an extra `.next()` in there and it skipped over them and everything worked. There's php generating the styles tags which is huge. Your answer would work for anyone else apart from that quirk in my code.